# subdomain routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When a user types in his username.example.com I read out the subdomain and render the users personal page.

```
map.home '', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

the problem is that I now want to add custom subdomains like www, '', help and so on.

What I do now but doesn't work:
I read the subdomain in the applications controller and when I catch help I redirect to the helps controller. Redirecting doesn't work because applications controllers is calles again and I end up in a infinit loop.

Someone knows how I approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a plugin for this:

http://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu